# Gunicorn show error only on log not on UI

Tags: debugging, gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn with for a Django Application `--log-level error --log-file /dev/stdout`. This also shows the error on the UI to the users.

I need to log errors to stdout, but on the UI, it should display Internal Server Error instead of full stack trace.

How to configure gunicorn for this ?.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set:

```
DEBUG = False
```

in your `settings`.